# How can I clean up this Ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

**The Problem**

I want to parse lines of a text box in order to generate items from it.

I've got it working but it looks ugly as sin.

How can I clean up that "if/else" mess?

**Code**

```
class LineParser
  def self.parse(line)
    line_matches = line.chomp.match(/(?<name>[[:print:]]+) \$(?<price>\d+\.*\d*)( +?(?<description_text>[^\+#]([[:print:]][^\+#])*))?( +?(\+(?<quantity>\d+)))?( +?#(?<cat1>[[:print:]][^#]*))?$/)
    return matches_to_hash(line_matches)
  end
  def self.matches_to_hash(matches)
    hash = {}
    keys = [:name, :price, :description_text, :quantity, :cat1]
    keys.each do |key|
      if key == :price
        hash[key] = matches[key].to_f
      elsif key == :quantity
        if matches[key].nil?
          hash[key] = 1
        else
          hash[key] = matches[key].to_i
        end
      else
        hash[key] = matches[key]
      end
    end
    hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for all the great suggestions. I've learned so much just from one question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed explicit return from parse.

```
class LineParser
  def self.parse(line)
    line_matches = line.chomp.match(/(?<name>[[:print:]]+) \$(?<price>\d+\.*\d*)( +?(?<description_text>[^\+#]([[:print:]][^\+#])*))?( +?(\+(?<quantity>\d+)))?( +?#(?<cat1>[[:print:]][^#]*))?$/)
    matches_to_hash(line_matches)
  end
  def self.matches_to_hash(matches)
    {
      :price            => matches[:price].to_f,
      :quantity         => (matches[:quantity] || 1).to_i,
      :name             => matches[:name],
      :description_text => matches[:description_text],
      :cat1             => matches[:cat1]
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hot damn, that's lovely. I hated doing that whole hash = {} return hash thing and I knew must have been a better way. This is it! Thanks.

Comment: mmm ruby :)

If you're in a situation where literals don't make sense, you can also use Object#tap.

Comment: the number of fields (5) it's in the edge. If I had 10 fields for example, I'd definitely go for a loop on the fields, but this is ok for 5.

Comment: @tokland agree, and would probably start pulling out constants and other refactoring

Comment: You need to a commas when building the hash {:thing1 => 1, :thing2 => 2}

Comment: Thanks, @drummondj. That's what I get for writing it in a scratch buffer. :)

Comment: Yeah, I just got that error myself but didn't get back to the question in time! :) I love Stack Overflow so much. Next time I get some crappy code I don't know how to improve, I'm posting it for sure. So many great answers here!

Answer (score 4):

This

```
if matches[key].nil?
  hash[key] = 1
else
  hash[key] = matches[key].to_i
end
```

is equivalent to

```
hash[key] = (matches[key] || 1).to_i
```

And for if/else chains with more than a couple of branches, maybe a case statement is more appropriate.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Superb! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To tidy matches_to_hash I would do:

```
def self.matches_to_hash(matches)
  hash = {}
  hash[:name] = matches[:name]
  hash[:price] = matches[:price].to_f
  hash[:description_text] = matches[:description_text]
  hash[:quantity] = matches[:quantity].nil? ? 1 : matches[:quantity].to_i
  hash[:cat1] = matches[:cat1]
  hash
end
```

But, I think I would just change parse to:

```
def self.parse(line)
  line_matches = line.chomp.match(/([[:print:]]+) \$(\d+\.*\d*)( +?([^\+#]([[:print:]][^\+#])*))?( +?(\+(\d+)))?( +?#([[:print:]][^#]*))?$/)
  hash = {}
  hash[:name] = $1
  hash[:price] = $2.to_f
  hash[:description_text] = $3
  hash[:quantity] = $4.nil? ? 1 : $4.to_i
  hash[:cat1] = $5
  hash
end
```

Comment: why create the hash in PHP-style?

Comment: Great point - I originally put the matches as named because it got me a hash like object, but if I need to manipulate it before I put it into the hash then there's not much point.

Comment: usual php-style: hash = {}; hash[:a] = 1. Other languages: hash = {:a => 1}.

Comment: Ah OK. Ruby supports both ways, so I'm not that picky. Whatever works that looks readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
class LineParser
  def self.parse(line)
    line_matches = line.chomp.match(/(?<name>[[:print:]]+) \$(?<price>\d+\.*\d*)( +?(?<description_text>[^\+#]([[:print:]][^\+#])*))?( +?(\+(?<quantity>\d+)))?( +?#(?<cat1>[[:print:]][^#]*))?$/)
    return matches_to_hash(line_matches)
  end
  def self.matches_to_hash(matches)
    hash = {}
    [:name, :price, :description_text, :quantity, :cat1].each do |key|
      case key
       when :price
         hash[key] = matches[key].to_f
       when :quantity
          hash[key] = 1 if matches[key].nil?
          hash[key] = matches[key].to_i unless matches[key].nil?
       else
         hash[key] = matches[key]
     end
     hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain why you're looping through the keys when each key does something different. Why not just handle them one by one?

```
class LineParser
  def self.parse(line)
    line_matches = line.chomp.match(/(?<name>[[:print:]]+) \$(?<price>\d+\.*\d*)( +?(?<description_text>[^\+#]([[:print:]][^\+#])*))?( +?(\+(?<quantity>\d+)))?( +?#(?<cat1>[[:print:]][^#]*))?$/)
    return matches_to_hash(line_matches)
  end
  def self.matches_to_hash(matches)
    hash = {}
    hash[:price] = matches[:price].to_f
    hash[:quantity] = (matches[:quantity] || 1).to_i
    hash[:name] = matches[:name]
    hash[:description_text] = matches[:description_text]
    hash[:cat1] = matches[:cat1]
    hash
  end
end
```

Note: I also stole the clever bit that Thilo posted about quantity.

Comment: that looks good, but no need to build the hash updating it. Simply build the hash in one step.

Comment: Yeah, looking back I'm not sure why either. I guess I thought it would reduce duplication and make the code simpler. Man, was I wrong! Thanks for your excellent suggestion.